# avg sale of quarter with previous quarter avg sale

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression, window-functions, analytic-functions

I have a table one in which there are various attribute like region product,year,qtr,month,sale. I have to calculate the avg_qtr sale of each product having same region and show their previous avg_qtr sale.I have read about lag but here it is not possible to use as it is not fixed after how many rows it will be repeated. My table structure is like this

```
   Region Product Year Qtr Month Sales 

    NORTH   P1    2015  1   JAN 1000
    NORTH   P1    2015  1   FEB 2000
    NORTH   P1    2015  1   MAR 3000
    NORTH   P1    2015  2   APR 4000
    NORTH   P1    2015  2   MAY 5000
    NORTH   P1    2015  2   JUN 6000
    NORTH   P1    2015  3   JUL 7000
    NORTH   P1    2015  3   AUG 8000
    NORTH   P1    2015  3   SEP 9000
    NORTH   P1    2015  4   OCT 1000
    NORTH   P1    2015  4   DEC 4000
    NORTH   P1    2015  4   NOV 2000
    NORTH   P3    2015  1   FEB 1000
    NORTH   P3    2015  1   FEB 9000
    NORTH   P3    2015  2   APR 2000
    NORTH   P3    2015  3   JUL 8000
    NORTH   P1    2016  1   MAR 3000
    NORTH   P1    2016  1   FEB 1000
    NORTH   P1    2016  1   JAN 2000
    SOUTH   P1    2015  1   JAN 2000
    SOUTH   P1    2015  1   FEB 3000
    SOUTH   P1    2015  1   JAN 4000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  1   MAR 1000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  1   JAN 8000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  1   FEB 9000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  2   JUN 9000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  2   MAY 8000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  2   APR 2000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  3   SEP 4000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  3   AUG 2000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  3   JUL 1000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  4   NOV 2000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  4   DEC 1000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  4   OCT 5000
    SOUTH   P3    2015  3   AUG 9000
    SOUTH   P3    2015  4   OCT 1000
    SOUTH   P3    2015  4   NOV 3000
    SOUTH   P2    2016  1   JAN 2000
    SOUTH   P2    2016  1   JAN 4000
```

I wrote the query which calculates current qtr and is showing previous one avg with current one

```
  WITH AvgSales
AS (SELECT
region,
product,
year,
qtr,
ROUND(AVG(sales), 2) AS avg_Sale
FROM one 
GROUP BY region,
product,
year,qtr
 )
SELECT
s.region,
s.product,
s.year,
s.month,
s.sales,
avg.qtr,
avg.avg_Sale AS Qtr_Avg_Sale,
prev.avg_sale AS Prev_Qtr_Avg_Sale
FROM one s
JOIN AvgSales avg
ON s.region = avg.region
AND s.product = avg.product
AND s.QTR = avg.qtr
AND s.year = avg.year
LEFT JOIN AvgSales prev
ON  (s.region = prev.region
AND s.product = prev.product
AND s.year - 1 = prev.year
and s.qtr=1
AND prev.qtr = 4) or
(s.region = prev.region
AND s.product = prev.product
AND s.year = prev.year
AND s.qtr - 1 = prev.qtr) ;
```

I am able to get current average and previous average of that product but not vice versa. I am not sure how to show the previous average of that quarter which does not have any sale in current quarter. 
I want a output like this-

```
Region  Product  Year  qtr  month   sale  avg_Sale     prev_avg_sale
    NORTH     P1     2015   1   JAN     1000    2000    
    NORTH     P1     2015   1   FEB     2000    2000    
    NORTH     P1     2015   1   MAR     3000    2000    
    NORTH     P1     2015   2   APR     4000    5000            2000
    NORTH     P1     2015   2   MAY     5000    5000            2000
    NORTH     P1     2015   2   JUN     6000    5000            2000
    NORTH     P1     2015   3   JUL     7000    8000            5000
    NORTH     P1     2015   3   AUG     8000    8000            5000
    NORTH     P1     2015   3   SEP     9000    8000            5000
    NORTH     P1     2015   4   OCT     1000    2333.33         8000
    NORTH     P1     2015   4   NOV     2000    2333.33         8000
    NORTH     P1     2015   4   DEC     4000    2333.33         8000
    SOUTH     P2     2015   1   JAN     8000    6000    
    SOUTH     P2     2015   1   FEB     9000    6000    
    SOUTH     P2     2015   1   MAR     1000    6000    
    SOUTH     P2     2015   2   APR     2000    6333.33         6000
    SOUTH     P2     2015   2   MAY     8000    6333.33         6000
    SOUTH     P2     2015   2   JUN     9000    6333.33         6000
    SOUTH     P2     2015   3   JUL     1000    2333.33       6333.33
    SOUTH     P2     2015   3   AUG     2000    2333.33       6333.33
    SOUTH     P2     2015   3   SEP     4000    2333.33       6333.33
    SOUTH     P2     2015   4   OCT     5000    2666.67       2333.33
    SOUTH     P2     2015   4   NOV     2000    2666.67       2333.33
    SOUTH     P2     2015   4   DEC     1000    2666.67       2333.33
    NORTH     P3     2015   1   FEB     9000    5000    
    NORTH     P3     2015   1   FEB     1000    5000    
    NORTH     P3     2015   2   APR     2000    2000           5000
    NORTH     P3     2015   3   JUL     8000    8000           2000
    SOUTH     P3     2015   3   AUG     9000    9000    
    SOUTH     P3     2015   4   OCT     1000    2000           9000
    SOUTH     P3     2015   4   NOV     3000    2000           9000
    NORTH     P1     2016   1   JAN     2000    2000         2333.33
    NORTH     P1     2016   1   FEB     1000    2000         2333.33
    NORTH     P1     2016   1   MAR     3000    2000         2333.33
    NORTH     P2     2016   2                   2000
    SOUTH     P2     2016   1   JAN     2000    3000         2666.67
    SOUTH     P2     2016   1   JAN     4000    3000         2666.67
    SOUTH     P2     2016   2                   3000  
    SOUTH     P1     2015   1   JAN     4000    3000    
    SOUTH     P1     2015   1   JAN     2000    3000    
    SOUTH     P1     2015   1   FEB     3000    3000
```

Comment: added the output also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the windowing clause of an analytic function if you have a single ordered value to sort by, so first create a `DENSE_RANK`ing of year and qtr, then use that ranking in your analytic functions:

```
with t1 as ( 
  select one.*
       , dense_rank() over (order by year, qtr) qord
    from one
)
select product
     , year
     , qtr
     , month
     , sales
     , round(avg(sales) over (partition by qord),2) qtr_avg
     , round(avg(sales) over (order by qord
                              range between 1 preceding
                                        and 1 preceding),2) prev_qtr_avg
  from t1
```

The above solution assumes dense quarterly data as provided in the sample data set, if however, the data is sparse along the quarter dimension you can first densify the data as in this query:

```
with qtrs as (select level qtr from dual connect by level <=4)
, t1 as ( 
  select product
       , year
       , qtrs.qtr
       , month
       , sales
       , dense_rank() over (order by year, qtrs.qtr) qord
    from qtrs
    left outer join one partition by (year)
      on one.qtr = qtrs.qtr
)
select product
     , year
     , qtr
     , month
     , sales
     , round(avg(sales) over (partition by qord),2) qtr_avg
     , round(avg(sales) over (order by qord
                              range between 1 preceding
                                        and 1 preceding),2) prev_qtr_avg
  from t1
```

This ensures that for every year represented in the data at least one row will exist for each quarter, and consequently QORD will enumerate every quarter, and gaps in the data will result in gaps in the calculated quarterly averages.

You can also achieve a similar effect by altering the way QORD is calculated by exploiting the numeric natures of YEAR and QTR as in this example:

```
with t1 as (select one.*, year*4+qtr qord from one)
select product
     , year
     , qtr
     , month
     , sales
     , round(avg(sales) over (partition by qord),2) qtr_avg
     , round(avg(sales) over (order by qord
                              range between 1 preceding
                                        and 1 preceding),2) prev_qtr_avg
  from t1
```

Here no densification was required, and yet it still correctly leaves gaps in the prev_qtr_avg, but it does leave out records for missing quarters which the densified data includes.

Combining the last two examples, and adding in your new requirement for regions a at least one row of data per quarter will be returned or generated if required for every distinct region, product and year.  Both averages are partitioned by region and product and calculated per current or previous quarter as the case may be:

```
with qtrs(qtr) as (select level from dual connect by level <= 4)
, t1 as (
select region, product, year, q.qtr, month, sales, year*4+q.qtr qord
  from qtrs q
  left join one partition by (region, product, year)
    on q.qtr = one.qtr
)
select region
     , product
     , year
     , qtr
     , month
     , sales
     , round(avg(sales) over (partition by region, product, qord),2) avg_sale
     , round(avg(sales) over (partition by region, product
                              order by qord
                              range between 1 preceding
                                        and 1 preceding),2) prev_avg_sale
  from t1
 order by year, region, qtr, product;
```

Comment: in your answer you have used range between and in my question it is there we can have a none sale in that quarter so it will fetch the sale of previous to previous quarter instead it shoul show null like if we don't have sale in quarter 3 of year 2015 so it should null avg for 4 qtr of 2015

Comment: Like if we dont have a sale in 2012 last quarter it is showing null in my output in question Your query will connect to last avg and I don't want that :(

Comment: I've added a second example showing how to densify the data using partitioned outer joins  so you get your required gaps

Comment: sorry my requirement changed with time and now I have a column for region also and now I have to partition on basis of each region, each product, each year and each quarter.Before that it was very different I have calculate simple avg now its quite different. So, I try to add region and product qtr in partition by of your example but for some product where there is no sale in previous quarter its showing other product avg sale in previous sale column.

Comment: and one more thing if there is no sale in current quarter its should previous avg sale. I worked out till the last condition but how to calculate sale if sale not in current quarter I am not getting it. I am adding my code also if you can please help me

Comment: I have also changed my output in question

Comment: Ok I've added another example based on your new requirement of having separate averages per region.

Answer (score 4):

Edited with the latest requirements.

Your problem is that you are trying to get the previous_avg by trying to manipulate QTR and YEAR.  I'm using the RANK function, ordering the way I want the data ranked.  In the joins I'm making sure that Average Region = Previous Region and disregarding year since the previous quarter could be Q4 of the Previous year for Average year Q1; it's cleaner this way.

```
    --Build the test table
    IF OBJECT_ID('SALES','U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE SALES

    CREATE TABLE SALES
    (
          Region  VARCHAR(255)
        , Product VARCHAR(10)
        , [Year]  INT
        , QTR     INT
        , [Month] VARCHAR(19)
        , Sales   DECIMAL(19,4)
    );

    INSERT SALES
    VALUES
         ('NORTH', 'P1', 2015, 1, 'JAN', 1000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2015, 1, 'FEB', 2000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2015, 1, 'MAR', 3000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2015, 2, 'APR', 4000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2015, 2, 'MAY', 5000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2015, 2, 'JUN', 6000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2015, 3, 'JUL', 7000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2015, 3, 'AUG', 8000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2015, 3, 'SEP', 9000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2015, 4, 'OCT', 1000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2015, 4, 'DEC', 4000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2015, 4, 'NOV', 2000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P3', 2015, 1, 'FEB', 1000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P3', 2015, 1, 'FEB', 9000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P3', 2015, 2, 'APR', 2000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P3', 2015, 3, 'JUL', 8000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2016, 1, 'MAR', 3000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2016, 1, 'FEB', 1000)
        ,('NORTH', 'P1', 2016, 1, 'JAN', 2000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P1', 2015, 1, 'JAN', 2000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P1', 2015, 1, 'FEB', 3000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P1', 2015, 1, 'JAN', 4000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2015, 1, 'MAR', 1000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2015, 1, 'JAN', 8000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2015, 1, 'FEB', 9000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2015, 2, 'JUN', 9000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2015, 2, 'MAY', 8000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2015, 2, 'APR', 2000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2015, 3, 'SEP', 4000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2015, 3, 'AUG', 2000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2015, 3, 'JUL', 1000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2015, 4, 'NOV', 2000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2015, 4, 'DEC', 1000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2015, 4, 'OCT', 5000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P3', 2015, 3, 'AUG', 9000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P3', 2015, 4, 'OCT', 1000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P3', 2015, 4, 'NOV', 3000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2016, 1, 'JAN', 2000)
        ,('SOUTH', 'P2', 2016, 1, 'JAN', 4000);


    --CTE TO CAPTURE AVG SALES BY REGION, PRODCUT, YEAR, QTR;  OMIT PRODUCT IF YOU WANT STRAIGHT UP QUARTER AVG, REGARDLESS OF PRODCUCT
    WITH cteAvgSales AS
    (
        SELECT Region, Product, [Year], QTR, AVG(Sales) current_avg
            , RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Region, Product, [Year], QTR) AS RNK
        FROM SALES
        GROUP BY Region, Product, [Year], QTR
    )
    SELECT s.Region, s.Product, s.[Year] AS [year], s.QTR AS [quarter], s.[Month], s.Sales, a.current_avg, p.current_avg AS previous_avg
    FROM SALES s
        INNER JOIN cteAvgSales a ON a.Region = s.Region
            AND a.Product = s.Product
            AND a.[Year]  = s.[Year]
            AND a.QTR = s.QTR
        LEFT JOIN cteAvgSales p ON p.Region = a.Region
            AND p.Product = s.Product
            AND p.RNK=a.RNK-1
    ORDER BY s.Region, s.Product, s.[Year], s.QTR
```

Comment: sorry my requirement changed with time and now I have a column for region also and now I have to partition on basis of each region, each product, each year and each quarter.Before that it was very different I have calculate simple avg now its quite different. So, I try to add region and product qtr in partition by of your example but for some product where there is no sale in previous quarter its showing other product avg sale in previous sale column and one more thing if there is no sale in current quarter its should previous avg sale I worked out till the last condition but don't know how to

Comment: show if there is no sale in current quarter :( I have made the code and it is not satisfying this last condition that if there no sale in current it should show null in that and it show previous sale avg in the previous avg column. I am adding my code also please if you can help

Comment: Update the answer and explained why you are having difficulty in the answer.  I ditched the method you are using because it was too messy and difficult match up the avg and prv_avg quaters.  Enjoy!

Comment: thanks again pal! but you didn't get my point anyway thanks a lot for your answer I had solved mine..your answer missed my last point of getting previous quarter avg if sale is none in current quarter...

Comment: If I missed the point, the point wasn't clearly made; the data you posted is exactly represented in the output created.  If you have another solution that answers your question more accurately, please post it so there is a correct answer to the question you have posed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to join on some sub-select statements that will get the previous quarter avg. You will also need to do a union of two statements because for quarters 2,3,4 you can simply subtract a quarter on the join statement to the previous qtr avg, but when it is the 1st quarter you need to subtract a year and set the previous qtr = 4. This statement should work for what you have described.

```
--handles when the current quarter being viewed is 2,3,or 4 because those would still be in the same year when looking at the previous quarter
select  t1.product,
        t1.year,
        t1.month,
        t1.sales ,
        t1.qtr,
        round(avg(t1.sales) over (partition by t1.qtr,t1.year),2) as av,
        t2.prev_av
from one t1
left join ( select
                product,
                year,
                month,
                sales ,
                qtr,
                round(avg(sales) over (partition by qtr,year),2) as prev_av
            from one
            ) t2
on t1.year = t2.year
and (t1.qtr - 1) = t2.qtr
where t1.qtr in (2,3,4)
union
--handles the 1st quarter of the year when you need to grab the 4th quarter of the previous year for the previous avg
select  t3.product,
        t3.year,
        t3.month,
        t3.sales ,
        t3.qtr,
        round(avg(t3.sales) over (partition by t3.qtr,t3.year),2) as av,
        t4.prev_av
from one t3
left join ( select
                product,
                year,
                month,
                sales,
                qtr,
                round(avg(sales) over (partition by qtr,year),2) as prev_av
            from one
            ) t4
on (t3.year - 1) = t4.year
and t4.qtr = 4
where t3.qtr = 1;
```

Comment: your query is working corrctly but it is heavy so can we make it much more optimal

Comment: you query has answer which is correct although my requirement afterwards changed. Anyway thank you....vote up for your answer

Comment: can you make it as I want??

Comment: yeah, what part of the requirement changed?

Comment: that only to use not that much select statement and mainly eliminate union

Comment: you may be able to do it using the lag function. Something like this. select product,
       year,
       month,
       sales ,
       qtr,
       round(avg(sales) over (partition by qtr,year),2) as av
       lag(round(avg(sales) over (partition by qtr,year),2),1,null) over (partition by qtr,year order by product,year,month,sales,qtr) as prev_avg
from one

Comment: yeah I have already tried it its hows this error-
 ''Window functions are allowed only in the SELECT list of a query.
           And, window function cannot be an argument to another window or group  function.''

Comment: May need to make another select statement on top of the first, however i'm not sure how much performance increase you will see with the windowing functions vs the union of sub-selects as the optimizer is probably doing the same thing with each in the background.

Comment: Yeah I have also done it earlier and yeah the performance change is not much