# avg sale of quarter with previous quarter avg sale

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have a table one in which there are various attribute like region product,year,qtr,month,sale. I have to calculate the avg_qtr sale of each product having same region and show their previous avg_qtr sale.I have read about lag but here it is not possible to use as it is not fixed after how many rows it will be repeated. My table structure is like this

```
   Region Product Year Qtr Month Sales 

    NORTH   P1    2015  1   JAN 1000
    NORTH   P1    2015  1   FEB 2000
    NORTH   P1    2015  1   MAR 3000
    NORTH   P1    2015  2   APR 4000
    NORTH   P1    2015  2   MAY 5000
    NORTH   P1    2015  2   JUN 6000
    NORTH   P1    2015  3   JUL 7000
    NORTH   P1    2015  3   AUG 8000
    NORTH   P1    2015  3   SEP 9000
    NORTH   P1    2015  4   OCT 1000
    NORTH   P1    2015  4   DEC 4000
    NORTH   P1    2015  4   NOV 2000
    NORTH   P3    2015  1   FEB 1000
    NORTH   P3    2015  1   FEB 9000
    NORTH   P3    2015  2   APR 2000
    NORTH   P3    2015  3   JUL 8000
    NORTH   P1    2016  1   MAR 3000
    NORTH   P1    2016  1   FEB 1000
    NORTH   P1    2016  1   JAN 2000
    SOUTH   P1    2015  1   JAN 2000
    SOUTH   P1    2015  1   FEB 3000
    SOUTH   P1    2015  1   JAN 4000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  1   MAR 1000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  1   JAN 8000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  1   FEB 9000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  2   JUN 9000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  2   MAY 8000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  2   APR 2000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  3   SEP 4000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  3   AUG 2000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  3   JUL 1000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  4   NOV 2000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  4   DEC 1000
    SOUTH   P2    2015  4   OCT 5000
    SOUTH   P3    2015  3   AUG 9000
    SOUTH   P3    2015  4   OCT 1000
    SOUTH   P3    2015  4   NOV 3000
    SOUTH   P2    2016  1   JAN 2000
    SOUTH   P2    2016  1   JAN 4000
```

I wrote the query which calculates current qtr and is showing previous one avg with current one

```
  WITH AvgSales
AS (SELECT
region,
product,
year,
qtr,
ROUND(AVG(sales), 2) AS avg_Sale
FROM one 
GROUP BY region,
product,
year,qtr
 )
SELECT
s.region,
s.product,
s.year,
s.month,
s.sales,
avg.qtr,
avg.avg_Sale AS Qtr_Avg_Sale,
prev.avg_sale AS Prev_Qtr_Avg_Sale
FROM one s
JOIN AvgSales avg
ON s.region = avg.region
AND s.product = avg.product
AND s.QTR = avg.qtr
AND s.year = avg.year
LEFT JOIN AvgSales prev
ON  (s.region = prev.region
AND s.product = prev.product
AND s.year - 1 = prev.year
and s.qtr=1
AND prev.qtr = 4) or
(s.region = prev.region
AND s.product = prev.product
AND s.year = prev.year
AND s.qtr - 1 = prev.qtr) ;
```

I am able to get current average and previous average of that product but not vice versa. I am not sure how to show the previous average of that quarter which does not have any sale in current quarter. 
I want a output like this-

```
Region  Product  Year  qtr  month   sale  avg_Sale     prev_avg_sale
    NORTH     P1     2015   1   JAN     1000    2000    
    NORTH     P1     2015   1   FEB     2000    2000    
    NORTH     P1     2015   1   MAR     3000    2000    
    NORTH     P1     2015   2   APR     4000    5000            2000
    NORTH     P1     2015   2   MAY     5000    5000            2000
    NORTH     P1     2015   2   JUN     6000    5000            2000
    NORTH     P1     2015   3   JUL     7000    8000            5000
    NORTH     P1     2015   3   AUG     8000    8000            5000
    NORTH     P1     2015   3   SEP     9000    8000            5000
    NORTH     P1     2015   4   OCT     1000    2333.33         8000
    NORTH     P1     2015   4   NOV     2000    2333.33         8000
    NORTH     P1     2015   4   DEC     4000    2333.33         8000
    SOUTH     P2     2015   1   JAN     8000    6000    
    SOUTH     P2     2015   1   FEB     9000    6000    
    SOUTH     P2     2015   1   MAR     1000    6000    
    SOUTH     P2     2015   2   APR     2000    6333.33         6000
    SOUTH     P2     2015   2   MAY     8000    6333.33         6000
    SOUTH     P2     2015   2   JUN     9000    6333.33         6000
    SOUTH     P2     2015   3   JUL     1000    2333.33       6333.33
    SOUTH     P2     2015   3   AUG     2000    2333.33       6333.33
    SOUTH     P2     2015   3   SEP     4000    2333.33       6333.33
    SOUTH     P2     2015   4   OCT     5000    2666.67       2333.33
    SOUTH     P2     2015   4   NOV     2000    2666.67       2333.33
    SOUTH     P2     2015   4   DEC     1000    2666.67       2333.33
    NORTH     P3     2015   1   FEB     9000    5000    
    NORTH     P3     2015   1   FEB     1000    5000    
    NORTH     P3     2015   2   APR     2000    2000           5000
    NORTH     P3     2015   3   JUL     8000    8000           2000
    SOUTH     P3     2015   3   AUG     9000    9000    
    SOUTH     P3     2015   4   OCT     1000    2000           9000
    SOUTH     P3     2015   4   NOV     3000    2000           9000
    NORTH     P1     2016   1   JAN     2000    2000         2333.33
    NORTH     P1     2016   1   FEB     1000    2000         2333.33
    NORTH     P1     2016   1   MAR     3000    2000         2333.33
    NORTH     P2     2016   2                   2000
    SOUTH     P2     2016   1   JAN     2000    3000         2666.67
    SOUTH     P2     2016   1   JAN     4000    3000         2666.67
    SOUTH     P2     2016   2                   3000  
    SOUTH     P1     2015   1   JAN     4000    3000    
    SOUTH     P1     2015   1   JAN     2000    3000    
    SOUTH     P1     2015   1   FEB     3000    3000
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32349374/440595 by the same author. Migrated for merge.